# how to get the desired result of inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class MonsterMash
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Monster moron = new Senator("jim","Georgia");
    System.out.println(moron.getName());
    System.out.println(moron.getState());
  }
}
```

This is the superclass

```
public class Monster
{
   String name;
   public Monster()
   {
     name="Dracula";
   }
  public Monster(String n)
  {
    name=n;
  }
  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }
}



public class Politician extends Monster
{
  public Politician(String n)
 {
    super(n);
 }
}

public class Senator extends Politician
{
  String state;

  public Senator(String n)
  {
    super(n);
    state="New Jersey";
  }
  public Senator(String n,String s)
  {
   super(n);
   state=s;
  }
  public String getState()
  {
    return state;
  }
}
```

After executing the program,The code doesn't produce the desired result.
I think i did something wrong one the main class.

My desired result is Jim Georgia.
what can i do to print it?

Comment: with the current state it´s impossible as everyone will be living in `New Yersey`

Comment: What is the difference between `public Senator(String n,Strings)` and `public Senator(String n,String s)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign Senator to Senator type reference, because you want to call method that belongs to Senator only.

```
    Senator moron = new Senator("jim","Georgia");
    System.out.println(moron.getName());// Monster/Polititian/Senator
    System.out.println(moron.getState());// Senator only
```

Answer (score 0):

You weren't using the value of s in your senator constructor

```
    public Senator(String n,String s)
  {
    super(n);
    state= s;  // This was set to a default value of "New Jersey" before
  }
```

and you need moron to be a Senator rather than a Monster. In Main:

```
 Senator moron = new Senator("jim","Georgia");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor of class `Senator` is setting the state value to 'New Jersey', your desired state value is never being set to the dynamic value you are passing from your `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

In class MonsterMash:

```
Senator moron = new Senator("jim","Georgia");
```

If you don't want to change here and keep dynamic binding than you will have to make both Monster and Politician class as abstract class and create abstract method getState() in both the classes:

```
public abstract class Monster {
    String name;
    public Monster()
    {
       name="Dracula";
    }
   public Monster(String n)
   {
       name=n;
   }
   public String getName()
   {
       return name;
   }

   abstract String getState();
}

public  abstract class Politician extends Monster{
 public Politician(String n)
 {
    super(n);
 }

 abstract String getState();
}
```